# Asymptote VS undefined point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When searching for asymptote how do I recognize that it is an undefined point rather than asymptote?

the one-sided limits at the asymptote should be $+-\infty$ and when is an undefined point the limits are finite?

Comment: Or perhaps the one-sided limits don't exist at all. Consider $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Vertical_asymptotes):

> a function $y=f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote $x=a$ iff at least one of
>   the limits:
>
> $$ \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) \qquad \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) $$
>
> is $\pm \infty$.

As an example, the function:
$$
y=\begin{cases}
x \quad for \quad x\le0\\
1/x \quad for \quad x>0
\end{cases}
$$
has the vertical asymptote $x=0$

Note that in this case the function is defined for $x=0$.